# Ganache-cli EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8545 error?

Tags: testrpc, ganache

when i start ganache-cli with command, it gives this error :

```
❯ ganache-cli
Ganache CLI v6.4.1 (ganache-core: 2.5.3)
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8545
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1510:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:142:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

so i checked which process am i using on port 8545, but it seemed like nothing.

```
❯ lsof -i :8545

~
❯
```

also, if i run `ganache-cli -p 7545`, i works on `127.0.0.1:7545` without any problems.

does anyone have any idea if this is a bug or i did something wrong starting ganache?

Comment: Restart your machine.

Comment: yes, i did a few times but nothing changed.

Comment: Oh, actually, I think I know what the problem might be. Did you happen to install Parity at some point? It automatically runs at start-up, and listens to 8545 by default. Look for a Parity process and shut it down, or alternatively, change your system settings to prevent it from running at start-up. Side note: it might also be the case for Geth.

Answer (score 1):

It solved with @goodvibration 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.check which process is using port 8545 ?

Ubuntu/mac -> **lsof -i :8545**

Windows ->**netstat -aof | findstr :8545**

2.kill the process

Ubuntu ->**pkill node**(process/COMMAND name form above output)

Windows ->try Task Manager

3.try to run **ganache-cli** agin